# How do I code AWS Lambda env variables using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have a SAM app which is working fine. Recently I've started using AWS lambda environment variables to remove some of the hardcoding in code. The issue here is that with the current SAM template.yaml, I need to add the AWS lambda env variables each time I deploy the app.

[Part required to be coded in SAM template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utTDQ.png)

When looking up SAM documentation, I see reference to variables like here but I don't think this is not the variable I'm after.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html

```
      Environment:
        Variables:
          MESSAGE: "Hello From SAM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at env variables defined through global variables. If you want to define them for individual `AWS::Lambda::Function`, you should use [AWS::Lambda::Function Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html).

This will allow you to define the variables for your function.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. That worked :)

I thought I tried that but oh well. Unfortunately I can't select your answer because of my reputation. Regardless, I appreciate the quick help.